# Python Range Function Functionality For Negative Values

Tags: python, numbers, range

Would like to know the working functionality of range() function in Python.

In below sample program, I want to print from -1 to -10. As Step Size is not provided, it will be by default taken as 1. Here step size is positive and I am printing negative numbers in decreasing order.

Atleast -1 should be printed during first pass, it may fail in second pass as -1 + 1 = 0 which does not lies in -1 to -10.

```
print("Start")
for index in range(-1,-10):
    print("Index is -", index)
print("Bye")
```

Can someone explain the inner implementation of range function and membership operator in.

Comment: "Atleast -1 should be printed during first pass," - That's not what [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) says: "For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and **r[i] < stop**. -1 is greater than the stop value -10, so it won't be part of the range.

Comment: From the documentation of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range): "For a positive step, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.". In your case `r[i]` is greater than `stop`.

Comment: Absolutely Right, It is mentioned in Python Doc, Thank You very much @ThierryLathuille and Matthias for clarifications and References.

Answer (score 1):

**You can add the step field in range function**

**Syntax** :-

```
for <variable> in range(start,end,step):
```

*step can be negative or positive*

The solution for your question is

```
for index in range(-1,-11,-1): 
print("Index is -", index)
```

Comment: I know How we get this fix but I was looking for the internal working rules for range function in Python - [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)